# Show that function $f$ is injective

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the binary function $f: \{0,2\}^{\mathbb{N}}\to [0,1]$ by
$$
f(\{a_n\})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{3^n}
$$
for $a_n\in \{0,2\}$.

I am working on the proof that $f$ is injective...

---

The proof will show $x \neq y$ implies $f(x) \neq f(y)$ which is the contrapositive of the definition of injectivity.

Since for $\{a_n\}\neq \{b_n\}$, there exists $N>0$ so that $a_n=b_n$ for $1\le n\le N-1$ but $a_N=b_N$, then
$$
f(\{a_n\})=\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^N\frac{a_k}{3^k}=:\lim_{N\to \infty} S_N
$$
and
$$
f(\{b_n\})=\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^N\frac{b_k}{3^k}=:\lim_{N\to \infty} L_N
$$

But what I am stuck is that the partial sum is
$$
S_N-L_N=\frac{a_N}{3^N}-\frac{b_N}{3^N}\to 0...
$$

This result is quite strange, as it suggests that when $N$ approaches infinity, the limits of the two are the same?

How to show that $f(\{a_n\})\neq f(\{b_n\})$?

Comment: the function is actually not injective (eg. the sequence 01111... gives the same result as 10000...)

Comment: you're now writing numbers in base 3 using only 0s and 2s, e.g. 0.002202200..., it is indeed injective

Comment: Also, minor point, if N = 1, then $1\leq n \leq N-1$ means n does not exist.  Is that Ok for the rest of your proof?

Comment: Also, please define $S_N$ and $L_N$.  I'm guessing they are partial sums for the first N terms.

Comment: Please add that in your actual question.  Comments might not get read and are subject to getting deleted at any time.

Comment: Don't you need to deal with the entire tail of each sum after N?  Not merely a single term from each sequence?

Comment: If you're trying a proof by contrapositive, or something similar, then you choose an epsilon in the ballpark of say $\frac{1}{2*(3^N)}$, then  and you've got all the essential details.  Show that the tail of each series after N, has an upper bound, and the upper bounds together are smaller than epsilon.
 You just need to flesh out a few steps.

Comment: Remember injectivity is defined by if $f(x)=f(y)$  then $x=y$.
The contrapositive is $x \neq y \rightarrow f(x) \neq f(y)$ 
 I'm not quite sure which context you're in, so you might adjust some notation or details for your course.

Comment: I didn't know if you were going for contrapositive, contradiction, or something else.  Now it's clear what you're trying to do.
The nature of proofs is you have to make clear to someone who might come from a completely different perspective.  Especially online, because we've never stepped foot in your class, met your professor, etc.

Comment: Towards the beginning, don't you mean $a_N \neq b_N$ instead of $a_N = b_N$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $N$ be the first number such that $a_N \neq b_N$. WLOG assume that $b_N - a_N = 2$. Now observe

$$ \frac{a_N}{3^N} + \sum_{n = N+1} \frac{a_n}{3^n} \leq  \frac{a_N}{3^N} + \sum_{n = N+1} \frac{2}{3^n} \leq  \frac{a_N+1}{3^N} <  \frac{b_N}{3^N}. $$

You can take it from here.

Comment: Arrggh, I spent forever writing my answer and then before I finish it, you posted a much cleaner answer.  Congratulations, I have some things to learn from you.

Comment: @nickalh Thanks, it was supposed to be a comment, but your conversation was a bit long so I put it as an answer. The OP can generalise this problem to base $p>3$ for fun using the same idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Clarification:
$$S_N= \sum_{k=1}^N\frac{a_k}{3^k}$$
and
$$L_N= \sum_{k=1}^N\frac{b_k}{3^k}$$
Denote the tails as $$R_N=\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty\frac{a_k}{3^k} \text{ and } M_N=\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{3^k} $$
Note: the tails begin *after* the Nth term, not at the Nth term.

$$|S_N-L_N|=|\frac{a_N}{3^N}-\frac{b_N}{3^N}|=\frac{2}{3^N}$$
is true.  However, there's no need to take a limit here.
The next goal is to show $|S_N - L_N| > \text{ maximum of }|R_N - M_N|$.  That is to say the difference in Nth partial sums is greater than the difference of the tails of {a_n} and {b_n}.

The maximum of $|R_N - M_N|$ has 2's for every difference of terms.   $$\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac{2}{3^k}=\frac{1}{3^N}$$
$$\frac{1}{3^N} < \frac{2}{3^N} = |S_N-L_N|$$  Thus we have proven a difference in any pair of term implies $f(\{a_n\})\neq f(\{b_n\})$